# Typescript Infer type params with Compiler API

Tags: typescript, typescript-compiler-api

With this code ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEkoGdnwComQFwDwAV4BeeAVwDsBrcgewHdyAaeAJWLKtoYD54BvAFDxh8bFmwAKAA4AuePgCUclgG4BAXwEDQSOImip4AWXggAHmPLA0mHPyEixOCQEc55UgFsARiBhL4bxoaCBAocjVNAWwATykEAGUAc3JcI14SE3NLawxxXABLcgAzP3lmItKYVl4AfngAbXxmFgBdeHcQADc-NVj4+GQU9mTU9JV4AHpJxo8fP2YgkLDyVqA)):

```js
declare class Test<P = unknown, R = unknown> {
    test(p: P): R;
}

declare class M extends Test {
    test(q: number): boolean;
}

// these lines are not in real code. This is an example of what TS
// could infer from my code and what I would like to find using Compiler API
type Sgn<M> = M extends Test<infer P, infer R> ? [P, R] : never;
type sgn = Sgn<M>; // [number, boolean]
```

typescript could infer implicit type arguments of class `M` (`P = number`, `R = boolean`) from method `test` in class declaration.

I want to do the same using [Compiler API](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API). I have `program.typeChecker` and I'm stuck here. How could I get implicit type arguments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type `Test` in `extends Test` of `M` is not implicitly typed as `Test<number, boolean>`. The class `M` overwrites the declaration of `test` to be `test(q: number): boolean`. If you get the type of the `ExpressionWithTypeArguemnts` in `extends Test` of `M` it will be `Test<unknown, unknown>`.

**Getting Types from `M`**

If you know what the structure of `Test` is and you have...

```
declare class M extends Test {
    test(q: number): boolean;
}
```

...and you want to find the type of the parameter and the return type of `test`, then you can do the following:

```
const mDecl = sourceFile.statements.find(child =>
    ts.isClassDeclaration(child) && child.name?.escapedText === "M"
)! as ts.ClassDeclaration;
const testMethod = mDecl.members.find(member =>
    ts.isMethodDeclaration(member)
    && ts.isIdentifier(member.name)
    && member.name.escapedText === "test"
)! as ts.MethodDeclaration;

// number type
typeChecker.getTypeAtLocation(testMethod.parameters[0]);
// boolean type
typeChecker.getReturnTypeOfSignature(typeChecker.getSignatureFromDeclaration(testMethod));
```

**Given `Test`, finding `P` and `R` in `M`**

If you have `Test` and want to find `P` and `R` in `M` and you don't know what the type of `Test` might look like, then you cannot use the previously described method.

To do this, you will have to traverse the type of `Test` manually and then traverse `M` in the same way and see what type the type parameters in `Test` are used in `M`. Doing this is kind of complicated and would be too much work/code to post here.

Basically, there's no easy way to build up types and then do comparisons with the compiler API. There are some proposals to make this easier (ex. [Type Builder API Proposal](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9883) and [Type Relationship API Proposal](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9879)).

That said, one way around it is to create a dummy file via `ts.createSourceFile` and write some code in there (ex. your `Sgn` and `sgn` declarations) then use the type checker on that file to resolve the types.

Comment: `Sgn` in question is just for reference what TS could infer and I would like to get without it.

Comment: I see in other words, you're suggesting to get type of `test` method

Comment: If I use a dummy file, I could find a way to add it to existing program. Do I have to create another program?

Comment: Nevermind. I've found [doc comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/f462576ac2cf32af0571819c528c0ff239cb65ee/src/compiler/program.ts#L773-L774) _A Program is an **immutable** collection_

Answer (score 0):

There is a new library that bring types to the runtime world https://deepkit.io/. You can use it to infer any type in your code.

It is a full framework but you can use the @deepkit/types and @deekit/type-compiler for what you want.